# How do I remove # in spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

Hi how do I remove the # in a row of thousands of numbers? I'm using google spread sheet. Thank you!

Comment: I mean the # symbol.

Comment: If its doable on excel I can transfer my data.

Comment: Just use `CTRL+H` and replace `#` with `' '` (blank) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a formula to remove your '#' symbol.

One simple way is to use 'substitute' :

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1; "#"; "")
```

You can find an spreadsheet example [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-0XtbDi8AehtBpvvfxe2b2E3kgXBH4FxvDViiq_TcWs/edit?usp=sharing)

- The A column contains your numbers with a # symbol.
- The B column contains the result of the formula.
- The C column is here to illustrate what formula is used in B column.

You can find the details of this formula here : [Substitute documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215?hl=en)